# Python spesific data name

Tags: python, loops

```
url = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/rest/api/studies/search/findByDiseaseTrait"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

data_dict = {}  # Dictionary to store the data for each disease trait

# Start the loop
while True:
    # Ask user for disease trait input
    disease_trait = input("Enter disease trait to search (or 'exit' to quit): ")
    
    if disease_trait.lower() == "exit":
        break  # Exit the loop if the user enters 'exit'
    
    query_params = {"diseaseTrait": disease_trait, "size": 200}
    response = requests.get(url, params=query_params, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        data_dict[disease_trait] = data["_embedded"]["studies"]
    else:
        print(f"Error occurred while retrieving content: {response.content}")

# Create a DataFrame from the collected data
df = pd.DataFrame()

for disease_trait, data in data_dict.items():
    df_temp = pd.json_normalize(data)
    df_temp["Disease Trait"] = disease_trait
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)

# Display the DataFrame
df
```

I create data with specific traits. But I cannot name data and data frame with user input. So when I searched 2nd trait first one deleted. How can I name data and the df?